# Message undefined and topic become buffer (ZMQ)

Tags: python, node.js, zeromq

I want to make publish and subscribe using ZeroMQ. I use python as publisher and node js as subscriber.

Here is the code :

**pub.py**

```
import zmq
import random
import sys
import time

port = "3001"
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    port =  sys.argv[1]
    int(port)

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:3001")
while True:
    topic = "hello"
    messagedata = "world"
    print "%s %s" % (topic, messagedata)
    socket.send("%s %s" % (topic, messagedata))
    time.sleep(1)
```

**sub.js**

```
var zmq = require ('zeromq')
var sock = zmq.socket ('sub');

sock.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:3001');
sock.subscribe('hello');
console.log('Subscriber connected to port 3001');

sock.on('message', function(topic, messagedata) {
  console.log('TOPIC', topic, 'DATA', messagedata);
});
```

But the result is, TOPIC become a buffer and DATA is undefined like this :

```
Topic <Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64> Data undefined
```

How to solve it? Thank You

Comment: Your output doesn't have `TOPIC` or `DATA` in caps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ZeroMQ `PUB.send()`-s a message body as-is:

Each of the **`SUB`**-side configured `<aTopicFILTER>`-strings is tested for left-side string-match against a message-body.

So your **`PUB`**-side has produced a message, having a positive mach with at least one **`SUB`**-side configured `<aTopicFILTER>`-string ( here the `"hello"` was set / matched ).

So such message was correctly delivered to **`SUB`** for any further processing:

```
>>> aTupleOfBYTEs = ( '\x68', '\x65', '\x6c', '\x6c', '\x6f', '\x20', '\x77', '\x6f', '\x72', '\x6c', '\x64' )
>>> aTupleOfBYTEs
('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd')
>>> print "".join( aTupleOfBYTEs )
hello world
```

Which exactly matches the published ZeroMQ API specification,
Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

While your code does exactly what is to be expected, it does not do  what you want it to do. It seems you want it to split the message into a topic (`'hello'`) and data (`'world'`).

The reason this does not happen, is that when you send your message, you combine the topic and the data to a single string, while your receiver expect it to be a multi-part message, split in two pieces. The simplest solution to this, is to actually generate a two-part message in your Python server.

Thus, replace

```
    socket.send("%s %s" % (topic, messagedata))
```

with

```
    socket.send_multipart([topic, messagedata])
```

and I expect your system to work as you intend it to.

Comment: Hi, thats works for me. And i use toString() on topic. Thanks for your help.!